# (N)Hibernate: deleting orphaned ternary association rows when either associated row is deleted

Tags: sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a ternary association table created using the following mapping:

```
<map name="Associations" table="FooToBar">
    <key column="Foo_id"/>
    <index-many-to-many class="Bar" column="Bar_id"/>
    <element column="AssociationValue" />
</map>
```

I have 3 tables, Foo, Bar, and FooToBar.

When I delete a row from the Foo table, the associated row (or rows) in FooToBar is automatically deleted. This is good.

When I delete a row from the Bar table, the associated row (or rows) in FooToBar remain, with a stale reference to a Bar id that no longer exists. This is bad.

How can I modify my hbm.xml to remove stale FooToBar rows when deleting from the Bar table?

Comment: Could you add your Foo and Bar mappings as well?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this... but you could get away by mapping FooToBar in Bar too, like this:

```
<map name="Associations" table="FooToBar">
    <key column="Bar_id"/>
    <index-many-to-many class="Foo" column="Foo_id"/>
    <element column="AssociationValue" />
</map>
```

Keep in mind NH does NOT know that `foo1[bar1]` and `bar1[foo1]` represent the same row, so be careful with the in-memory state (that is, don't access the elements from both sides in the same session)